# Phonegap Build + Windows phone app + "Can't install company app error"

Tags: html, cordova, windows-phone-8, phonegap-build

I'm getting ""Can't install company app error " when im installing my app xap on windows 8 mobile phone. I want to build the xap through phonegap build.https://build.phonegap.com

My zip contains following file hierarcy

```
css
js
index.html
config.xml
ic_launcher.png
```

my config.xml file is

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="io.cordova.hellocordova" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>Roadrunner</name>
    <description>
       Be prepared on road - Navigational app focus towards road safety
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="winphone">

    </platform>
</widget>
```

Um getting the following error.
Can't install company app error -- There is a problem with this comapny app.
Please help me out/

Comment: Is your phone set to allow "third-party" applications to load?

Comment: how can i make it in windows phone.i tried but so far no good way turn it on

Comment: I do not use windows phones. I think the problem is your phone needs an administrator to allow install Apps. You do not on Android or iOS. Does your phone belong to a company your work for?

Answer (score 0):

change your app id

```
<widget id="io.cordova.hellocordova"
```

to

```
<widget id="com.yourcompanydomain"
```